# Necessary - Having to

Tags: grammar

Being locked into a contract, it's (having - necessary) to bring out the new album these days.

I am one of those who will choose 'necessary' at first sight, but my tutor said that 'it' here the common subject of the two clauses: the conjunction of the first is left out and gerund is used instead. And it may refer to 'the band' for example.

My question is that can the adjective 'necessary' used in this question.

Comment: That sentence is wrong either way because "these days" doesn't apply to a necessary action *right now*.

Answer (score 0):

Your tutor is only half right: the "it" *could* be the subject of both sentences, and it *could* refer to "the band", but it's not clear.

The "it" could also a "dummy" pronoun, and the sentence could mean something like:

> Because they're locked into a contract, it's necessary to bring out the album.

Comment: But when I leave out 'because', we use gerund and the subject must be common in both sentences to avoid the sentence being a dangling one, so it must be here the subject.

Comment: @MohammedSalim That's true, but that rule only applies to real subjects, not "dummy" subjects. The rule is more like, "*the main clause cannot have a real subject that is different from the implied subject of the "ing" phrase*". So in this case, it's OK.